# escapping PHP + HTML into to PHP string

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have to adapt a webpage (on PHP) to ajax, but I'm having a really hard time into manually escaping a HTML+PHP code into a PHP string.
More specifically I have to escape the following piece of code (details are not important)

**HTML**

```
<div id="accordion">
    <?php foreach ($processs as $process){ ?>
        <label><?php echo $process['opperation'] . '.' . $process['codigo'] . ' ' . $process['nome']; ?></label>
        <div>
        <table id="<?php echo $process['id']; ?>">
            <tr>    <th>subprocesss chave</th>              <th>Inhabilitar</th>    </tr>                   
                <?php   $subprocesss = $objControlopperation->obtersubprocesss($process['id']);
                        if (count($subprocesss)){
                            foreach ($subprocesss as $subprocess){ ?>   
            <tr>   <td> <?php echo $process['opperation'] . '.' . $process['codigo'] . '.' . $subprocess['codigo'] . ' ' . $subprocess['nome'] ?></td>    
                <td >  
                    <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $subprocess['id']; ?>" onClick="habilitada('<?php echo $subprocess['id']; ?>','<?php echo $process["id"]; ?>')"  />
                </td> </tr>
                      <?php }
                       }?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" >
                    Nova subprocess: 
                <input type="text" id="<?php echo 'novoRegistro_'.$process['id']; ?>" />
                <label onclick="adicionarCaracteristica('<?php echo $process['id']; ?>')">Adicionar</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
```

into something similar to this:

**PHP**

```
   $html = "
            <tr>    <th>subprocesss chave</th>              <th>Inhabilitar</th>    </tr>";

   $subprocesss = $objControlopperation->obtersubprocesss($process['id']);
        if (count($subprocesss)){
            foreach ($subprocesss as $subprocess){ 
                $html .= "<tr>   <td>".
                            $process['opperation'] . '.' . $process['codigo'] . '.' . $subprocess['codigo'] . ' ' . $subprocess['nome'].
                            " </td> <td > <input type=\"checkboxid=\"". 
                             $subprocess['id'].
                             "\" onClick=\"habilitada('" . 
                               $subprocess['id'] .
                               "\',\'" .
                               $process["id"] . 
                               "\')\"  /> </td> </tr> "; 

            }
        };
        $html .="<tr>
                 <td colspan=\"3\" >
                  Nova subprocess: 
                  <input type=\"text\" id=\"novoRegistro_'" . 
                                    $process['id'] . 
                                    "\" /> <label onclick=\"adicionarCaracteristica('<" . 
                                    $process['id'] .
                                    "')\">Adicionar</label> </td></tr>";


    }
```

I need to do this since the $html variable is the new piece of webpage generated by AJAX. The problem is that this has to be done in different places, so I was wondering if there is some tool that can facilitate the escaping process.
This is the first time I work with AJAX, so any hint or idea to tackle this kind of problems are very welcome.

Comment: Personally, I would suggest just sticking with singly-quoted strings and concatenating as necessary.  That is of course unless you are looking to use a templating system or `sprintf` or similar to clean things up.

Comment: I don't see why you're moving from what you had in the first block to the second. If you think Ajax requires this, you must be really confused.

Comment: Ajax just returns whatever the called PHP prints to a javascript callback. It will do that whether you use style 1 or style 2...and style 2 is just plain ugly. Not to mention that concatenating whole pages of HTML into a string will use more resources and so shouldn't be done when not necessary. And its not necessary just because you're using Ajax.

Comment: I don't have a clue on where to find an example; I just need a hint on how to look for a solution.

Comment: I think everyone just gave you a solution... that you don't need to load everything into a single string in order to output HTML content in response to a AJAX request.

Comment: Sure, but how do I output. Any special PHP command?

Comment: you're using ajax via javascript, most likely. Show us the javascript handler. Typically you output the results there. If you call a php script at all it is "outputting" so in your case you would use the js callback to append the html to some dom element

Comment: Yeah, only send what you have to and use javascript for the html side of things

Comment: Tanks, I'll do it tomorrow as I don't have the whole code with me

Answer (score 1):

I like my code to be readable and easy to maintaint (if possible), so I would write the first part like so:

```
    $subprocesss = $objControlopperation->obtersubprocesss($process['id']);
    if (count($subprocesss)){
        foreach ($subprocesss as $subprocess){ 
            $html .= sprintf(
            '<tr>
                <td>%s.%s.%s.%s</td>
                <td>
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        id="%s"
                        onclick="habilitada( %s , %s )"/>
                </td>
            </tr>',
            $process['opperation'],
            $process['codigo'],
            $subprocess['codigo'],
            $subprocess['nome'],
            $subprocess['id'],
            $subprocess['id'],
            $process["id"]
        );
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replays as you mentioned I code the HTML part once and reused it on AJAX without any change. Here is the code.

The View:

```
<?php
    $HTML =' <table class="tabela">
          <tr><th><h2>Configurar PRO</h2></th></tr>
          <tr><td><div id="accordion"> ';
        foreach ($processos as $processo){
            $HTML.= sprintf('
                <label> %s.%s %s  </label>
                <div><table id="tabela_%s" ',
                    $processo['cerne'],
                    $processo['codigo'],
                    $processo['nome'],
                    $processo['id'],
                    $processo['id']);
            $HTML.= $objControlCERNE->montarPratica($processo);
            $HTML.='</table></div> ';
        }
    $HTML.='</div></td></tr>
        </table>';
    echo $HTML;
?>
```

The controller. Where obterProcessos and obterPraticas query the DB to obtain a list of the processe(s) and practice(s).

The JS handler

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function habilitada(pratica_id, processoinfo, idResponse){
        var task = "<?php echo TASK.'habilitar_desabilitarPraticas&pratica_id='; ?>"+pratica_id;

        alert(task+'   idResponse: '+idResponse);

        enviarViaAjax(task,idResponse);
    }

</script>

<?php
class Control_PRO{

    public function obterProcessos(){
        try{
            $objPRO_DAO = new PRO_DAO();
            return $objPRO_DAO->obterProcessos();
        }catch(Exceptio $ex){
            if ($ex->getCode()==0){
                echo '<pre>';
                debug_print_backtrace();
                throw new Exception('Error no metodo: '. __METHOD__ . ' tabela: '. $tabela, 1);
            }
            throw new Exception($ex->getMessage());
        }
    }
    private function obterPraticas($processo_id){
        try{
            $objPRO_DAO = new PRO_DAO();
            return $objPRO_DAO->obterPraticas($processo_id);
        }catch(Exceptio $ex){
            if ($ex->getCode()==0){
                echo '<pre>';
                debug_print_backtrace();
                throw new Exception('Error no metodo: '. __METHOD__ . ' tabela: '. $tabela, 1);
            }
            throw new Exception($ex->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Finally montar pratica is the HTM segment that is gonna be send back by AJAX

```
    public function montarPratica($processo){

            $HTML ='<tr>    <th>Práticas chave</th> <th>Inhabilitar</th>    </tr> ';
            $objControlPRO = new Control_PRO();
            $praticas = $objControlPRO->obterPraticas($processo['id']);
            if (count($praticas)){
                foreach ($praticas as $pratica){
                    $HTML.=sprintf(' <tr> 
                                            <td> %s.%s.%s.%s </td>
                                            <td> <input type="checkbox" id="%s" onClick="habilitada(%s,\'%s\')" %s> </td> 
                                    </tr> ',
                            $processo['PRO'],
                            $processo['codigo'],
                            $pratica['codigo'],
                            $pratica['nome'],
                            $pratica['id'],
                            $pratica['id'],
                            "tabela_".$processo["id"],
                            $pratica['ativada']==1 ? 'checked' : "");
                }
            }
            return $HTML.sprintf('  <tr>
                                            <td     colspan="3" >
                                            Nova prática:
                                            <input type="text" id="novoRegistro_%s" />
                                            <label onclick="adicionarCaracteristica(%s)">Adicionar</label> </td>
                                        </tr>',
                    $processo['id'],
                    $processo['id']);
    }
}
```

and AJAX

```
function createRequestObject() {
        var ro;//objeto request
        if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
            ro = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }else{
            ro = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
            return ro;
}

var http_A01 = createRequestObject();//agora a variável http_A01 contém os atributos de um objeto request.
var divResposta;

    function enviarViaAjax(task, idResponse) {

        //alert("task:"+task+"   idResponse:"+idResponse);
        divResposta = idResponse;

      http_A01.open("post", ""+task);//abrindo conexao
      http_A01.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      http_A01.setRequestHeader("charset", "charset=UTF-8");
      http_A01.onreadystatechange = handleResponse_A01;//assim que o satus for alterado entrará no método de resposta
      http_A01.send();//enviando os paramentros para o teste.php
    }

    function handleResponse_A01() { //metodo de retorno

        /*  readyState:
                0: request not initialized
                1: server connection established
                2: request received
                3: processing request
                4: request finished and response is ready
        */
```